# Schlüpfer - regionale Bedeutungsunterschiede

Tags: meaning, regional

Ich habe heute erfahren, dass das Wort »Schlüpfer« offenbar in Deutschland auch ein Synonym für »Unterhose« ist. Eine kurze Recherche im Internet hat widersprüchliche Resultate ergeben. Auf einigen Seiten wird »Schlüpfer« als eine Herren-Unterhose mit kurzem Beinansatz definiert, andere Seiten meinen, das Wort stünde für alle Arten von Unterhosen, für beiderlei Geschlecht.

Ich wiederum kannte bis vor wenigen Stunden nur diese Bedeutung:
Schlüpfer: Flache Schuhe ohne Schuhbänder, in die man einfach nur hineinschlüpft, also Mokassins, Espandrillos, Slipper und dergleichen.

Da ich bei meiner Internet-Recherche bisher nichts genaues darüber herausfinden konnte, würde mich nun interessieren, in welchen Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums das Wort »Schlüpfer« mit welcher Bedeutung verknüpft ist.

Im Osten Österreichs (Steiermark, Wien) ist ein Schlüpfer jedenfalls nur ein Schuh. Eine andere Bedeutung hat das Wort hier nicht. Ich habe aber heute gelernt, dass in der Gegend rund um Leipzig die Schuh-Bedeutung völlig unbekannt zu sein scheint, während dort mit Schlüpfer jede Art von Unterhose gemeint ist, egal wie sie geschnitten ist und egal für welches Geschlecht sie bestimmt ist.

Comment: “Mokassins, Espandrillos, Slipper und dergleichen”. Oh, you mean thongs ;)  (Imagine an Australian accent.)

Comment: Mir (Südwestdeutschland, speziell Kurpfalz = badisch-hessisch-pfälzerisches Übergangsgebiet) war das Wort ursprünglich gar nicht bekannt. Erst in Südniedersachsen ist es mir begegnet, überwiegend in der Bedeutung ‘Damenunterhose’, nie in der Bedeutung ‘Schuh’. Im Variantenwörterbuch steht es leider nicht.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bei uns in Süddeutschland ist einzig nur die Bedeutung als Damenunterhose bekannt. Damit gehen wir konform mit den Bedeutungseinträgen in diversen Wörterbüchern:

- [cannoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=schl%EF%BF%BDpfer&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=de)
- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schl%C3%BCpfer)
- [thefreedictionary](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/schl%C3%AF%C2%BF%C2%BDpfer)
- [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schluepfer)

Interessant ist, dass Duden noch eine weitere, mir bislang völlig unbekannte Bedeutung eines weiten Herrenmantels auflistet.

Offenbar ist die Bedeutung als Unterhose noch recht neu. In Grimms Wörterbuch wird als [Schlüpfer](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS12579) noch etwas, in das man hineinschlüpft (z.B. Muff) genannt. So ist denkbar, dass sich die Bedeutung davon ausgehend in Österreich anders entwickelt hat. Immerhin schlüpft man in Pantoffeln ja auch hinein.

**Anmerkung:** Dieses Wortes ist veraltet und wird meist durch den moderneren Begriff *"Slip"* ersetzt, der sowohl für eine Damen- als auch für eine Herrenunterhose benutzt wird.

Answer (score 13):

Ich komme aus Berlin, bin durch schwäbisch/westfälische Eltern aber sehr vielfältig geprägt.
Mir war nur die Bedeutung für jede Art von Unterhose bekannt, die Verwendung des Wortes für Schuhe ist mir neu.

Answer (score 12):

Thüringen und Sachsen: Jede Art von Unterhose. Deswegen wird Martini hier auch als Schlüpferstürmer bezeichnet.

Comment: Das wäre aber durchaus auch konsistent damit, nur Damenunterhosen als Schlüpfer zu bezeichnen, auch wenn ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob der [Schlüpferstürmer](http://miniaturflaschen.de.tl/Galerie/pic-1000405.htm) bei ihm oder ihr anzuwenden ist, um ihm das Erstürmen ihres Schlüpfers zu erleichtern.

Comment: ...und es wird hierzulande wegen der vielen schwierigen Buchstaben auch liebevoll *Schlübba* ausgesprochen.

Comment: Der Schlüpferstürmer wird natürlich bei ihr angewendet. Welcher Mann trinkt denn bitte Martini? Ach, solche. Na, dann geht es bestimmt auch für Männerunterhosen. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Die Bezeichnung „Schlüpfer“ für Schuhe ist mir – in Sachsen-Anhalt gebürtig – unbekannt.

Schlüpfer, lokal auch *„Schlüpper“*, bezeichnet hier nach meinem Dafürhalten relativ eng anliegende Unterhosen *ohne* Beinansatz, sowohl für den Herren als auch die Dame, bei ersterem mit oder ohne Eingriff. Knappere Passformen werden dabei eher als *„Slip“* bezeichnet. Diese Bezeichnung kostet Einheimische etwas Überwindung, wird aber dann für *alle* Schlüpfer verwendet, wenn der Sprecher etwas auf sich hält.

Diese Entwicklung könnte dazu beigetragen haben, dass der Schlüpfer [vor einigen Jahren Platz 10 der Liste „vom Aussterben bedrohte Wörter“](http://www.welt.de/kultur/article936844/Kleinod-und-Schluepfer-vom-Aussterben-bedroht.html) einnahm. Über jüngere Entwicklungen der Verwendung vor Ort müsste ich mich fernmündlich informieren.

Böse Zungen aus benachbarten und kulturell wenig verbundenen Bundesländern behaupten übrigens, dass der Begriff „Schlüpfer“ vor allem jenen Exemplaren vorbehalten ist, die sich neben besonders konservativer Schnittführung auch durch zeitloses weißes [Doppelripp](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelripp) und entsprechend geringes erotisches Potential auszeichnen. Letzteres gilt im Zweifelsfall aber für alle als „Schlüpfer“ bezeichneten Unterhosen.

Comment: Im Mansfelderland spricht man gerne auch mal vom Schlübber

Comment: Schlüpfer mit Beinansatz kann auch noch dazugehören. Nur mit langem Bein sind es dann immer Unterhosen. Manche differenzieren anscheinend danach statt bei den kurzen Varianten Synonyme zu sehen.

Answer (score 8):

Ich kenne den Schlüpfer hier in Westfahlen auch als Bezeichnung für eine „normale” Unterhose für den Mann oder die Frau. Also nicht String-Tanga oder Boxer-Shorts. Die Bezeichnung Schlüpfer für Schuhe habe ich wiederum noch nie gehört.

Answer (score 6):

Ich kenne Schlüpfer ausschließlich als Unterhose, und zwar meist in der Bedeutung für Damenunterhosen (Slips). Keinesfalls würde man das beispielsweise für einen String-Tanga nehmen (zu viel Wort für zu wenig Stoff :-D).

Würdest Du das für Schuhe (Slipper) verwenden, würdest Du in Deutschland vermutlich ausgelacht, nachdem das Missverständnis aufgeklärt wurde.

Comment: "Schlüpfer" (1 Wort mit 9 Buchstaben) ist zu viel Wort für zu Wenig Stoff, aber "String-Tanga" (zusammengesetztes Wort mit 11 Buchstaben und einem Bindestrich) ist dafür nicht zu viel Wort?

Comment: Genau dieses Auslachen ist mir im Gespräch mit einem Deutschen passiert. Daher habe ich ja überhaupt erst diese Frage gestellt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast *Zu viel Wort*: Da hast Du auch Recht. Aber deswegen ja auch der Smiley. Jetzt könnte man die These aufstellen *je kleiner die Unterhose, desto länger die Bezeichnung*...